# Can linear programming be used to solve Ax = b equations?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Assume that we have a system $Ax = b$ and we want to solve that with constraints.

Can linear programming be used to solve the $x$ from $Ax = b$?

Assume that we have the objective function

$$max : c^T x$$
With the constraints:

$$
x \ge 0 \\
Ax \le b$$

This is on the standard form of linear programming.

What should $c$ vector be then? Should it be $c = A^T b$ ?

Comment: I think the purpose of this exercise is to understand that any linear program can be written in standard form. Basic idea: maximize $0(x^+ - x^-)$ subject to $x^+ \geq 0, x^- \geq 0, A(x^+ - x^-) \leq b, -A(x^+ - x^-) \leq b$.

Comment: @littleO Why x+ and x- ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pratical answer. I'm using GNU Octave's linear programming tool: https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Linear-Programming.html

```
>> A = [1 2; 1 -4]
A =

   1   2
   1  -4

>> b =  [2; 5]
b =

   2
   5

>> c = A'*b
c =

    7
  -16

>> x = glpk(c, A, b, [0;0], [], "UU", "CC", -1) % -1 is for maximize
x =

   2
   0

>>
```

The objective function is (and also need to be $c^T = A^Tb$)

$$ max: A^T b x$$

And the constraints are

$$ x \ge 0\\ Ax \le b$$

If I ignore the constraints and only do linear solving 
$$x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$
Then the solution $x$ would be.

```
>> x = linsolve(A, b)
x =

   3.00000
  -0.50000

>>
```

I have created a C-function named linprog in EmbeddedLapack here. Very easy to use for embedded system if you need optimization there.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack

Comment: @Rahul math is quite fuzzy and so are the questions as well. But read the question again. I'm talking about constraints.

Comment: @Rahul The reason why everyone else interpret this question differently is because they are reading the title. The main head question says that there is constraints included. :) Also to include, math becomes very fuzzy. I like to make it practical as possible and my "proofs" is to use software to compute :)

Comment: If everyone is misunderstanding your question, and you refuse to clarify your question, then all the best of luck to you my friend.

Comment: @Rahul Not sure if all misunderstanding my question. But all I say is to read the question, and not focus on the title only.

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

1. Rewrite $Ax=b$ as $Ax \le b$ and $-Ax\le -b$.
2. Rewrite $x$ as $x^+ - x^-$, where $x^+ \ge 0$ and $x^- \ge 0$.

Explicitly:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &0(x^+ - x^-) \\
&\text{subject to} &A(x^+ - x^-) &\le b \\
&&-A(x^+ - x^-) &\le -b \\
&&x^+ &\ge 0 \\
&&x^- &\ge 0
\end{align}
Now this is standard form because all constraints are $\le$ and all variables are nonnegative.
To recover $x$ after you solve, compute $x=x^+ - x^-$.

Comment: So the constraints need to be $-Ax \le -b$ and x...?

Comment: Can you rewrite the whole objective function and its constraints?

Comment: Take $c=0$ for the objective.

Comment: But that won't help me right?

Comment: @littleO wrote it out in a comment, except you need to change $b$ to $-b$ in the second constraint.

Comment: Ok ! -Ax <= -b only? But why x+ and x-?

Comment: The motivation for $x^+$ and $x^-$ is to rewrite your free variable $x$ into standard form, which requires nonnegative variables.

Comment: But that's not practical in C programming language.

Comment: If I'm using the dual problem for LP?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying. I'm not going to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explicit formulation just now.

Comment: Hi rob! Thanks for a more clear answer. Have a look at my answer. I solved the problem. And the objective function cannot be zero.

Comment: I don't see anything that prevents all the objective function coefficients from being 0.  Also, you can use "S" for equality constraints, so you don't need to reformulate the $Ax=b$ as two inequalities.  If you can somehow pass $\text{lb}= -\infty$, you can avoid the $x = x^+ -x^-$ transformation.

Comment: No no. Try to set c = 0 and solve. You will not get a good answer. But if you set c = A'*b, then you will get the best answer. No need to set lb = -inf. Just set it to lb = 0.

Comment: Not c = 0.  Try c = [0; 0].  Also, if the only solution x has some negative value, your lb = 0 will prevent finding it.

Comment: Yes. But that's the key with my question. Solve Ax= b with constraints. If I set c = [0;0] then I get x = [0,0].

Comment: You need "SS" instead of "UU" if you want Ax=b.

Comment: Look at my constraints. It says <= and >=